# How can I optimise this SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, query-optimization

I'm writing a piece of software that is meant to identify files that have been put onto the web server (CMS) but are no longer needed and should/could be deleted.

To start with I'm trying to reproduce all required steps manually.

I'm using a batch script executed in the webroot to identify all (relevant) files on the server. Then, I'm importing the list to SQL Server and the table looks like this:

```
id   filename
1    filename1.docx
2    files/file.pdf
3    files/filename2.docx
4    files/filename3.docx
5    files/file1.pdf
6    file2.pdf
7    file4.pdf
```

I also have a CMS database (Alterian/Immediacy CMC 6.X) which has 2 tables storing page content: page_data and PageXMLArchive.

I would like to scan the database to see if the files from the first table are referenced anywhere in the content of the site - p_content column from page_data table and PageXML column from PageXMLArchive table.

So I have a loop which gets each filename and checks if it's referenced in any of those tables, if it is it skips it, if it ain't it adds it to a temporary table.

At the end of the query the temporary table is displayed.

Query below:

```
DECLARE @t as table (_fileName nvarchar(255))
DECLARE @row as int
DECLARE @result as nvarchar(255)

SET @row = 1


WHILE(@row <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ListFileReport))
BEGIN
    SET @result = (SELECT [FileName] FROM ListFileReport WHERE id = @row)

    IF ((SELECT TOP(1) p_content FROM page_data WHERE p_content LIKE '%' + LTRIM(RTRIM(@result)) + '%') IS NULL) OR ((SELECT TOP(1) PageXML FROM PageXMLArchive WHERE PageXML LIKE '%' + LTRIM(RTRIM(@result)) + '%') IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @t (_fileName) VALUES(@result)
    END

    SET @row = @row + 1

END

select * from @t
```

Unfortunately due to my poor SQL skills the query takes over 2 hours to execute and times out.

How can I imporve that query, or change it to achieve a similar thing without having to run 1000s of WHERE x LIKE statements on ntext fields? I can't make any changes to the database, it has to stay untouched (or it won't be supported - big deal for our customers).

Thanks

**EDIT:**
Currently I'm working around the issue by batching the results few hundred at a time. It works but takes forever.

**EDIT:**

Can I possibly utilise Full-Text search to achieve this? I am willing to take a snapshot of the database and work on the copy if there is a way of changing the schema to achieve the desired results.

page_data table:

```
USE [TD-VMB-01-STG]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[page_data]    Script Date: 12/13/2011 13:19:15 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[page_data](
    [p_page_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [p_title] [nvarchar](120) NULL,
    [p_link] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [p_content] [ntext] NULL,
    [p_parent_id] [int] NULL,
    [p_top_id] [int] NULL,
    [p_stylesheet] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [p_author] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [p_last_update] [datetime] NULL,
    [p_order] [smallint] NULL,
    [p_window] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [p_meta_keywords] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
    [p_meta_desc] [nvarchar](2000) NULL,
    [p_type] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
    [p_confirmed] [int] NOT NULL,
    [p_changed] [int] NOT NULL,
    [p_access] [int] NULL,
    [p_errorlink] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [p_noshow] [int] NOT NULL,
    [p_edit_parent] [int] NULL,
    [p_hidemenu] [int] NOT NULL,
    [p_subscribe] [int] NOT NULL,
    [p_StartDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [p_EndDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [p_pageEnSDate] [int] NOT NULL,
    [p_pageEnEDate] [int] NOT NULL,
    [p_hideexpiredPage] [int] NOT NULL,
    [p_version] [float] NULL,
    [p_edit_order] [float] NULL,
    [p_order_change] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [p_created_date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [p_short_title] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [p_authentication] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [aaaaapage_data_PK] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [p_page_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[page_data] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_page_data_p_order]  DEFAULT (0) FOR [p_order]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[page_data] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__Temporary__p_con__1CF15040]  DEFAULT (0) FOR [p_confirmed]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[page_data] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__Temporary__p_cha__1DE57479]  DEFAULT (0) FOR [p_changed]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[page_data] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__Temporary__p_acc__1ED998B2]  DEFAULT (1) FOR [p_access]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[page_data] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__Temporary__p_nos__1FCDBCEB]  DEFAULT (0) FOR [p_noshow]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[page_data] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__Temporary__p_edi__20C1E124]  DEFAULT (0) FOR [p_edit_parent]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[page_data] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF__Temporary__p_hid__21B6055D]  DEFAULT (0) FOR [p_hidemenu]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[page_data] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_page_data_p_subscribe]  DEFAULT (0) FOR [p_subscribe]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[page_data] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_page_data_p_pageEnSDate]  DEFAULT (0) FOR [p_pageEnSDate]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[page_data] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_page_data_p_pageEnEDate]  DEFAULT (0) FOR [p_pageEnEDate]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[page_data] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_page_data_p_hideexpiredPage]  DEFAULT (1) FOR [p_hideexpiredPage]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[page_data] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_page_data_p_version]  DEFAULT (0) FOR [p_version]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[page_data] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_page_data_p_edit_order]  DEFAULT (0) FOR [p_edit_order]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[page_data] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_page_data_p_order_change]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [p_order_change]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[page_data] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_page_data_p_created_date]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [p_created_date]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[page_data] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_page_data_p_authentication]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [p_authentication]
GO
```

PageXMLArchive table:

```
USE [TD-VMB-01-STG]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[PageXMLArchive]    Script Date: 12/13/2011 13:20:00 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PageXMLArchive](
    [ArchiveID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [P_Page_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [p_author] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [p_title] [nvarchar](400) NULL,
    [Version] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PageXML] [ntext] NULL,
    [ArchiveDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PageXMLArchive] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ArchiveID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PageXMLArchive] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_PageXMLArchive_ArchiveDate]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [ArchiveDate]
GO
```

Comment: Can you include the structure of your page_data and PageXMLArchive tables in the question?

Comment: For starters you should move the `SELECT COUNT(*)` above the `WHILE` and put the result into a variable. To avoid doing that query for every row.

Comment: @MarkBannister added table structure. Thanks

Comment: @Johan Thanks. Moving SELECT COUNT(*) above the WHILE loop does make no difference what so ever. Just ran the query. :(

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid the loop in many ways, and here is an example...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  ListFileReport
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT *
     FROM   page_data
     WHERE  p_content LIKE '%' + LTRIM(RTRIM(ListFileReport.FileName)) + '%'
    )
  AND
  NOT EXISTS (
     SELECT *
     FROM   PageXMLArchive 
     WHERE  PageXML LIKE '%' + LTRIM(RTRIM(ListFileReport.FileName)) + '%'
    )
```

Note: This removes the loop, and will yield a massive improvement because of that.  But it still has to parse the whole of both lookup tables for every entry in ListFileReport, without any clever algorithmics, s their could be no useful indexing.  So it will still be slow as a dog, it'll just have one broken leg instead of two.

The only way to avoid using LIKE is to parse all of the fields in the `page_data` and `PageXMLArchive` tables and create a list of referenced files.  As HTML and XML are very structured, this can be done, but I'd look for a library or something to do it for you.

Then, you can create a another table with all of the files, without duplication, and with an appropriate index.  Querying against that instead of using LIKE will be massively faster.  I have no doubts at all.  But writing or finding the code will be a chore.

Comment: Thanks. For testing purposes I ran the the query (only part of it querying page_data table, leaving PageXMLArchive out) and my query finishes in 5:04 mins, while your takes 5:09mins. This is only on page_data table (1600 rows). PageXMLArchive is 16000 rows. Moved the COUNT query outside of the loop and running it now. Will report back in a sec.

Answer (score 0):

A stored procedure especially has a loop with `select` and `insert` mixed will defiantly slow down the query.

ideally if you could `insert into @table select a, b from table` it will millions time faster than insert each row separately.

For your example, could do something like:

> insert into @t (_fileName) select ... from  p_content join ...on .. where sth like %sth

let me know if it is not applicable.

Comment: I don't think it's an INSERT that's causing the delay. It's the SELECT * FROM X WHERE Y LIKE '%Z%' on ntext columns in 2 tables with 17000 rows in total. Also each row's ntext field will contain whole page of XML/HTML code.